# How do I allow users to close a slide using this JQuery example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I would like to get users to sign up to my email newsletter without using annoying popups.

I discovered a scroll-activated JQuery slide that I think will work well.

Here is the test example I created: (scroll down to activate it)

http://buckinvestor.com/test/jquerytest.html

Now here is the problem:  I don't want to annoy users by constantly having this slide down on each page.

1. How do I add a "Close" button to the slide?
2. How do I ensure that the user doesn't see the slide again after they click close?  (perhaps a cookie that stays active for 7 days or something?, not sure how that works, but if you provide me some guidance, I'll figure it out).

Thank you everyone - StackOverflow has been such a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

Easy

you just need to hide the DIV
in this example add a button or image and use the live('click',function(){})

```
    $('#closediv').live('click',function(){
$('#headerSlideContainer').hide();})
```

as for the second part of the question yes cookie

Comment: Thank you Russell, can you guide me on the cookie part?  Like I said, just guide me and I'll figure it out.  thank you so much!

Comment: Sure I use a plugin called jquery.cookie.js
http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Russell, but can you show me exactly where I would have to put the cookie code within the JQuery  for this to work?  I want the cookie to expire in 10 days.  I added the "hide" animation already:  http://buckinvestor.com/test/jquerytest.html

Comment: you need to put it when the page loads, ie $(document).ready function

Answer (score 1):

For #1, just add a button and

```
$("button.hide").click(function(event){ $("div.hidethis").hide() });
```

onclick to hide the div that is the slide thing.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<a>` or `<button>` or something for the close button inside of the #headerSlideContent `<div>`

Add a on click or similar to the button inside your load function:

```
$('#closeButton').click(function(){
   $('#headerSlideContainer').hide();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

For part 2, yes a cookie is good, I found the jQuery cookie plugin to be helpful: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Set the cookie: `$.cookie("name", "value");`

Read the cookie: `var value = $.cookie("name");`